# SQL Server Adding Missing Data Values to Interval Query

Tags: sql-server, intervals

I am currently working my way through a reporting requirement and am stuck on the best way to proceed from where I am.

I have a table that captures interval data for a number of requests per 15 min interval along with an identifier for what type of request is being made.

Another table holds the details of the request name.

Data is only written from the source app if a particular request has been made in an interval. The result is that there are gaps in the interval table data for a given type of request. I don't have control over the Source App and can't insert data into the interval table. Everything has to be sorted out downstream of that.

On the output side, I need to generate the missing data. Currently this is being done manually and with some Excel wizardry and several hours per week, but I feel like I'm also pretty close to solving the issue on the SQL side, I'm just missing the last hop. (I think)

The following query is representative of the data structures.

I am generating the intervals in the range, then joining that with the two data tables. That gets closer to what I'm looking to do but I'm not sure how to account for both tables missing values appropriately.

I am trying to get the output to look like:

```
interval               |CommonName      |aCounter
=======================|================|===============
all intervals          |each CommonName | value -or- 0
2018-06-17 14:00:00.000|NameOne         | 0
2018-06-17 14:00:00.000|NameTwo         | 0
2018-06-17 14:15:00.000|NameOne         | 1
2018-06-17 14:15:00.000|NameTwo         | 2
2018-06-17 14:30:00.000|NameOne         | 3
2018-06-17 14:30:00.000|NameTwo         | 0
2018-06-17 14:45:00.000|NameOne         | 0
2018-06-17 14:45:00.000|NameTwo         | 0
```

The query that gets me closest to this output is:

```
declare @DateFrom datetime = '2018-06-17 14:00:00'
declare @DateTo datetime = '2018-06-17 15:00:00'
declare @Incr int = 15
declare @values table (interval datetime)
declare @dataOne table (interval datetime, identifier varchar(4), aCounter int)
declare @dataTwo table (identifier varchar(4), commonName varchar(50))

--populate the @values table
Begin
    With DateTable As (
        Select DateFrom = @DateFrom
        Union All
        Select DateAdd(MI, @Incr, df.DateFrom)
        From DateTable df
        Where df.DateFrom < @DateTo
    )
    Insert into @values(interval) Select DateFrom From DateTable option (maxrecursion 32767)
End

--populate the @dataOne table
insert into @dataOne values ('2018-06-17 14:15:00.000','500',1)
insert into @dataOne values ('2018-06-17 14:15:00.000','501',2)
insert into @dataOne values ('2018-06-17 14:30:00.000','500',3)
insert into @dataOne values ('2018-06-17 14:30:00.000','502',4)

--populate the @dataTwo table
insert into @dataTwo values ('500', 'NameOne')
insert into @dataTwo values ('501', 'NameTwo')
insert into @dataTwo values ('502', 'NameThree')

select vals.interval
    ,IsNull(dt.commonName,'none') as CommonName
    ,IsNull(do.aCounter,0)  as aCounter
from @values vals
    left join @dataOne do
        on vals.interval = do.interval
        and do.identifier in ('500','501')
    left join @dataTwo dt
        on do.identifier = dt.identifier
```

But this produces output like:

```
interval               |CommonName      |aCounter
=======================|================|===============
2018-06-17 14:00:00.000|none            |0
2018-06-17 14:15:00.000|NameOne         |1
2018-06-17 14:15:00.000|NameTwo         |2
2018-06-17 14:30:00.000|NameOne         |3
2018-06-17 14:45:00.000|none            |0
2018-06-17 15:00:00.000|none            |0
```

Which is closer but not really where I am trying to get to.

Can someone suggest a better alternative to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit #1**
I realized that my original post may have been missing details. The Cross Join solution below is accounting for missing intervals and I am looking to account for both missing intervals and missing values out of dataTwo. If I modify the data fed into the solution provided by @Aaron Dietz it highlights what I'm trying to say. There is a record in dataTwo that has no corresponding dataOne record. I flipped around some of the joins in the generation of existing data but that didn't produce the right result either so I backed up.

I also changed the Temp Table to a table var because I have to run everything in SSMS and can't touch any schema, even temp tables. I realize this exposes potential execution/performance issues at scale but it's what I have to work with.

```
declare @dataOne table (interval datetime, identifier varchar(4), aCounter int)
declare @dataTwo table (identifier varchar(4), commonName varchar(50))

insert into @dataOne values ('2018-06-17 14:15:00.000','500',1)
insert into @dataOne values ('2018-06-17 14:15:00.000','501',2)
insert into @dataOne values ('2018-06-17 14:30:00.000','500',3)
insert into @dataOne values ('2018-06-17 14:30:00.000','502',4)

insert into @dataTwo values ('500', 'NameOne')
insert into @dataTwo values ('501', 'NameTwo')
insert into @dataTwo values ('502', 'NameThree')
insert into @dataTwo values ('503', 'NameFour')

--Create a temp table to store processed output records
declare @Final table (interval datetime, CommonName varchar(50), aCounter int)

--Populate #Final with interval records that already exist
INSERT INTO @Final (interval, CommonName, aCounter)
SELECT d.interval, d2.commonName, d.aCounter
FROM @dataOne d
JOIN @dataTwo d2 on d.identifier = d2.identifier
WHERE d.identifier IN ('500','501','502','503')

--Set beginning and end intervals
DECLARE @Start datetime = '2018-06-17 14:00:00.000'
DECLARE @End datetime = '2018-06-17 15:00:00.000'

--Loop through intervals and insert missing records
WHILE (@Start <= @End)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Final (interval, CommonName, aCounter)
    SELECT @Start, CommonName, 0
    FROM (SELECT @Start interval) A
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CommonName FROM @Final) B
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM @Final F
                      WHERE F.interval = A.interval
                      AND F.CommonName = B.CommonName)

SET @Start = DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, @Start)
END

--Final output
SELECT *
FROM @Final
ORDER BY interval, CommonName
```

**Edit #2**
For the clarified information above in Edit #1, I am trying to get the output to look like:

```
interval               |CommonName      |aCounter
=======================|================|===============
all intervals          |each CommonName | value -or- 0
2018-06-17 14:00:00.000|NameOne         | 0
2018-06-17 14:00:00.000|NameTwo         | 0
2018-06-17 14:00:00.000|NameThree       | 0
2018-06-17 14:00:00.000|NameFour        | 0
2018-06-17 14:15:00.000|NameOne         | 1
2018-06-17 14:15:00.000|NameTwo         | 2
2018-06-17 14:15:00.000|NameThree       | 0
2018-06-17 14:15:00.000|NameFour        | 0
2018-06-17 14:30:00.000|NameOne         | 3
2018-06-17 14:30:00.000|NameTwo         | 0
2018-06-17 14:30:00.000|NameThree       | 4
2018-06-17 14:30:00.000|NameFour        | 0
2018-06-17 14:45:00.000|NameOne         | 0
2018-06-17 14:45:00.000|NameTwo         | 0
2018-06-17 14:45:00.000|NameThree       | 0
2018-06-17 14:45:00.000|NameFour        | 0
```

The associated intervals are non-existent for "NameFour" so it should display zeros for each interval.

I **think** the following query works by changing the joins in the 'already exists' query into the temp table and moving the identifier filter to the outermost query.

```
--Set beginning and end intervals
DECLARE @Start datetime = '2018-06-17 14:00:00.000'
DECLARE @End datetime = '2018-06-17 15:00:00.000'

declare @dataOne table (interval datetime, identifier varchar(4), aCounter int)
declare @dataTwo table (identifier varchar(4), commonName varchar(50))

insert into @dataOne values ('2018-06-17 14:15:00.000','500',1)
insert into @dataOne values ('2018-06-17 14:15:00.000','501',2)
insert into @dataOne values ('2018-06-17 14:30:00.000','500',3)
insert into @dataOne values ('2018-06-17 14:30:00.000','502',4)
insert into @dataOne values ('2018-06-17 15:30:00.000','502',4)

insert into @dataTwo values ('500', 'NameOne')
insert into @dataTwo values ('501', 'NameTwo')
insert into @dataTwo values ('502', 'NameThree')
insert into @dataTwo values ('503', 'NameFour')

--Create a temp table to store processed output records
declare @Final table (interval datetime, CommonName varchar(50), identifier varchar(4), aCounter int)

--Populate #Final with interval records that already exist
INSERT INTO @Final (interval, CommonName, identifier, aCounter)
SELECT ISNULL(d.interval,@Start), d2.commonName, d2.identifier, ISNULL(d.aCounter,0)
FROM @dataOne d
RIGHT OUTER JOIN @dataTwo d2 
    on d.identifier = d2.identifier
    and d.interval>=@Start and d.interval<=@End
ORDER BY ISNULL(d.interval,@Start), d2.commonName, ISNULL(d.aCounter,0)

--Loop through intervals and insert missing records
WHILE (@Start <= @End)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Final (interval, CommonName, identifier, aCounter)
    SELECT @Start, CommonName, identifier, 0
    FROM (SELECT @Start interval) A
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CommonName, identifier FROM @Final) B
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM @Final F
                      WHERE F.interval = A.interval
                      AND F.CommonName = B.CommonName)

SET @Start = DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, @Start)
END

--Final output
SELECT *
FROM @Final
WHERE identifier in ('500','501','502','503')
ORDER BY interval, CommonName
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to insert the records that exist, then use a loop to insert the missing interval records:

```
--Set beginning and end intervals
DECLARE @Start datetime = '2018-06-17 14:00:00.000'
DECLARE @End datetime = '2018-06-17 15:00:00.000'

declare @dataOne table (interval datetime, identifier varchar(4), aCounter int)
declare @dataTwo table (identifier varchar(4), commonName varchar(50))

insert into @dataOne values ('2018-06-17 14:15:00.000','500',1)
insert into @dataOne values ('2018-06-17 14:15:00.000','501',2)
insert into @dataOne values ('2018-06-17 14:30:00.000','500',3)
insert into @dataOne values ('2018-06-17 14:30:00.000','502',4)
insert into @dataOne values ('2018-06-17 15:30:00.000','502',4)

insert into @dataTwo values ('500', 'NameOne')
insert into @dataTwo values ('501', 'NameTwo')
insert into @dataTwo values ('502', 'NameThree')
insert into @dataTwo values ('503', 'NameFour')

--Create a temp table to store processed output records
declare @Final table (interval datetime, CommonName varchar(50), identifier varchar(4), aCounter int)

--Populate #Final with interval records that already exist
INSERT INTO @Final (interval, CommonName, identifier, aCounter)
SELECT ISNULL(d.interval,@Start), d2.commonName, d2.identifier, ISNULL(d.aCounter,0)
FROM @dataOne d
RIGHT OUTER JOIN @dataTwo d2 
    on d.identifier = d2.identifier
    and d.interval>=@Start and d.interval<=@End
WHERE d.identifier in ('500','501','502','503')
--ORDER BY ISNULL(d.interval,@Start), d2.commonName, ISNULL(d.aCounter,0)

--Loop through intervals and insert missing records
WHILE (@Start <= @End)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Final (interval, CommonName, identifier, aCounter)
    SELECT @Start, CommonName, identifier, 0
    FROM (SELECT @Start interval) A
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CommonName, identifier FROM @dataTwo) B
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM @Final F
                      WHERE F.interval = A.interval
                      AND F.CommonName = B.CommonName)

SET @Start = DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, @Start)
END

--Final output
SELECT *
FROM @Final
ORDER BY interval, identifier
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this - it works excellently on the original data set of 2-3 values. I realized there's another case to consider where there are no interval records in dataOne but there are dataTwo records to consider as well. I will add to to the original post to see if that clarifies the piece that's missing. Do you think that a second Insert based on the missing dataTwo values would do the trick?

Comment: @SeanNilsen I think I see what you mean with the new dataset example, but could you add the new desired output to your question to clear things up?

Comment: Updated with Edit #2. Also added my work-in-progress that seems to resolve it.

Comment: @SeanNilsen Got it now -- I changed a couple things and updated my answer.  I put the identifier filter back into the first insert and changed the cross join to look at `@datatwo`.  Originally it was looking at `@final` because I thought you wanted to filter out `NameFour`.  Ultimately both ways work, but you should see a little better performance keeping the filter earlier on in the query.

Comment: @SeanNilsen Also commented out the `ORDER BY` in the first insert since that will force a sort and be overridden by the final ordering (you may have had that there just for testing), and I changed the final ordering to match your expected result (although I'm not sure if ordering by `identifier` will always work properly, it does with the sample data)